# e.Row.DataItem error in gridview rowdatabound event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, rowdatabound

[image]
I want to enable or disable a particular row according to the related user logined. So i use rowdatabound event but i have an error in this line:

```
DataRow drv = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
```

In here, e.Row.DataItem has related row information. I have controlled and it has values of row. But when i want to continue, i take this error:

> Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`14[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.DateTime,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]]' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

Then I have changed this line:

```
DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
```

For this condition, it gives no error but drv has still null value. Dataitem does not assign its value.

In here, related full code:

```
protected void gvListele_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    dbeDataContext db = new dbeDataContext();
    var c = (from v in db.CAGRIs where v.UserID != Convert.ToInt32(Session["user"]) select v).ToArray();
    if (c != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in c)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                 DataRow drv = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row; 

                int tempID = Convert.ToInt32(drv["CagriID"].ToString());
                if (item.CagriID == tempID)
                {
                    e.Row.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What can i do for this error ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not a `DataRowView` as you've already noticed. Choose a different datasource than an anonymous type and cast it correctly. What _is_ the `DataSource` currently?

Comment: what's wrong with `DataRow drv = e.Row`?

Comment: for better performance, the `if statement` should be at the top of this method. before you fetch all those `CARGIs`

Comment: in fact why are you fetching on each `RowDataBound` that looks like a query that should have been executed outside of this method completely.

Comment: i have edited by adding picture to show dataitem for datasource.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have solved my problem two days ago. I've used this:

```
int callID = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CagriID"));
```

All the event:

```
    protected void gvListele_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    dbeDataContext db = new dbeDataContext();
    var c = (from v in db.CAGRIs where v.UserID != Convert.ToInt32(Session["user"]) select v).ToArray();
    if (c != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in c)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                int callID = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CagriID"));
                if (callID == item.CagriID)
                {
                    e.Row.Enabled = false;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a few suggestions which may help fix your issue.

firstly where you select `var c` I would place this outside of this method.
for now I will use a property

```
public object Cagris
{  
    get
    {
        if(_cagris == null)
        {
             _cagris =  (from v in db.CAGRIs 
                         where v.UserID != Convert.ToInt32(Session["user"]) // the session variable I would also have as a property rather than access it each time like this. 
                         select v).ToArray();
        }
        return _cagris;
    }
}


protected void gvListele_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        if (Cargis != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Cargis)
            {
                //now you can either get the DataRow  
                DataRow dr = e.Row;
                int tempID = int.Parse((string)dr["CagriID"]);

                if (item.CagriID == tempID)
                {
                    e.Row.Enabled = false;
                }


                //or use the DataItem
                Cagris c = (Cagris)e.Row.DataItem;

                if (item.CagriID == c.CagriID)
                {
                    e.Row.Enabled = false;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i take this error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow' to 'System.Data.DataRow' for DataRow dr = e.Row;

Comment: For Cagris c = (Cagris)e.Row.DataItem line, i take this error: Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`14[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.DateTime,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]]' to type 'CAGRI'.